# How to inspect the Android device using chrome?

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, remote-debugging

Is there I way that someone can help me fixing a problem ! I am trying to do some remote debugging for my Android app. I am using chrome tools to inspect the device. When I open that I can see that my device is recognized by chrome however that inspect button that usually appears is not there. In short, chrome can see the device but I can't really go an inspect it. I followed the Remote debugging tutorial for chrome I've done all of the steps and it seems that when all of that is done a button for inspect should be there; but it's not for my case ! Any help ???

Answer (score 1):

If you are on android 4.4 or greater you can add this code on the onCreate method:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

Then your app should appear on chrome

You can also try gapdebug to debug phonegap apps https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/

Comment: The code I posted won't work, but you can use gapdebug

Comment: Thx a lot  it's just an awesome tool ! Thank You :):)

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of app do you want to debug with the Google Chrome Web Inspector?

As far as I know you can use the Chrome Tools to debug web pages in the Google Chrome app on your mobile device. So if you have the Chrome app and at least one tab opened you should be able to inspect the tab's contents.

I don't think any further debugging in your apps is supported.

Comment: I am trying to debug a Cordova app that has been built and run on the android phone. I am not using a google chrome app or any web pages. My mobile app is created using Ionic and Cordova frameworks. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which Cordova and Android-Versions are you using? Did you set the "Debuggable Flag" in the Android Manifest? Are you building in the debug mode? Take a look at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap#chrome-remote-debugging

Comment: I am using 4.2.0 cordova and 4.3 version of android . I will check out the tutorial .. Thanks alot